# Choosing a Flavorless Oil with Specific Qualities

Tags: oil

I'm looking for a cooking oil that's flavorless.

Many people like coconut oil, but I think it has too strong of a smell. Olive oil, while noticeably less pungent, is still noticeable. I'm also trying to avoid most nut-derived oils, to avoid possible unwanted allergic reactions.

I'm leaning towards something that's low in trans fat and relatively high in polyunsaturated fat. Something that'll stay liquid (even when kept in the fridge) would be nice.

Comment: Sunflower oil maybe?

Comment: Why would you keep it in the fridge?

Answer (score 1):

You could try Rice Bran oil. It is virtually flavourless and I've used it for anything from salad dressings to frying. It has 37% polyunsaturated fats. The smoking point is 232 Celsius.

Comment: Hello Nette, and thank you for writing an answer. Note that health is off topic on the site. If the OP specifies a specific measurable condition for nutrients (like in this case "high in PUFA"), it is OK to give a number for it. But we don't give any possible health advice beyond that, like discussing what effects it has been shown to have, etc. I had to remove that part of your answer so it will stay on topic. But no worries, the rest is good as it is.

Comment: Can get rid of the health advice but let's keep the nutritional information in here still.

It is also high in omega 6 & 9 fatty acids. It has extremely low levels of omega 3.

Answer (score 0):

Sunflower oil is really the only one that meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Safflower oil is probably your best bet! Very light, unsaturated fat, almost no flavor. It also stands up well to high temps.